# What is the use of DMatrix?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

The docs say:

> Data Matrix used in XGBoost. DMatrix is an internal data structure
> that is used by XGBoost, which is optimized for both memory efficiency
> and training speed. You can construct DMatrix from multiple different
> sources of data.

I get this bit but what's the difference/use of DMatrix instead of a Pandas Dataframe?

Comment: When quoting documentation, please do include the relevant link.

Comment: Apologies weren't aware I had to do that. Thank you though for informing me. I will be sure to share the link.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When using the [XGBoost Python package](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/index.html) you can choose between two different APIs to train your model. XGB's own [Learning API](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.training) and the [Scikit-Learn API](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn).
When using the Scikit-Learn API data is passed to the model as numpy array or pandas dataframes.
When using the Learning API data is passed using the DMatrix.

Have a look at the [python examples](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/demo/guide-python), to see both APIs used.

Basically you already found the *"use of DMatrix instead of a Pandas Dataframe"* in the [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.core): It is a data structure the XGBoost developers created for *"memory efficiency and training speed"* with their machine learning library.

Comment: Thank you. This actually helps me understand. 
If I may ask, what's the benefit of using Learning API against the Scikit-Learn API, or is that just a personal preference?

Comment: Mostly a matter of personal preference. Obviously the scikit-learn API makes it easy to utilize some of the useful tools available in scikit-learn (model selection, pipelines etc.).

Comment: Is there a way I can print DMatrix?

Comment: @Tyr1on. I think we can. So if you do `dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train_features, label=train_label)` then simply do `dtrain.get_data().A` to display the matrix