# xgboost.fit() vs. xgboost.train()

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I am looking over [the docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html) in XGBoost, but I am not understanding 1) if there are any differences between using `xgboost.fit()` vs. `xgboost.train()`, and 2) if there are any advantages/disadvantages using one over the other?

I think the only one I've identified so far is that you can specify more `params`  with the train() function, but I'm not entirely sold that you cannot specify those same `params` somewhere within the fit() function as well.

Comment: `xgboost.train()` is for global configuration object right? and `xgboost.fit()` here `xgboost` is instance of some `regression` or `classification` class. And if not please point towards documentation of both `train()` and `fit()`.

Answer (score 2):

Taking most points from [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70161725/17312591) on the use of DMatrix in xgboost:

1. The XGBoost Python package allows choosing between two APIs. The [Scikit-Learn API](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn) has objects `XGBRegressor` and `XGBClassifier` trained via calling `fit`.
   XGBoost's own [Learning API](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.training) has xgboost.train.
   You probably could specify most models with any of the two choices.
2. Mostly a matter of personal preference. The scikit-learn API makes it easy to utilize some of the tools available in scikit-learn (model selection, pipelines etc.)